# How to find the variable $k$ which minimizes the function $\Omega^2$?

Tags: equation-solving

$$\Omega^2(k) = 4(\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(km)}{m^{1+\alpha}})(\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(km)}{m^{1+\alpha}} - A^2)$$

Let $A = 1$ and $\alpha = 1$ and write $w(k) := \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(km)}{m^{1+\alpha}}$. I am told that there exists a unique $k$, call it $k_{max}$, which minimizes $\Omega^2$ where $k_{max}$ satisfies $w(k_{max}) = \frac{A^2}{2}$ and $\Omega^2(k_{max}) = -A^4$.

[image]

$\epsilon=1$ in the above. However, in my attempt to compute this $k_{max}$

```
\[Alpha] = 0.7;
A = 1;
M = 5;
f[k_, \[Alpha]_, M_] := 
  Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, M}];
Solve[f[k, \[Alpha], M] == A^2/2 &&  
  4 f[k, \[Alpha], M] (f[k, \[Alpha], M] - A^2) == -A^4, k]
```

this yields an empty solution. Did I write my Mathematica code correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_, α_] := Assuming[0 < k < Pi,
  Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify]

kmax = With[{A = 1, α = 1}, 
  ArgMin[{4 f[k, α] (f[k, α] - A^2), 0 < k < Pi}, k] // 
   Simplify]

(* π - Sqrt[-2 + π^2] *)
```

Verifying,

```
{4 f[kmax, α] (f[kmax, α] - A^2) == -A^4, f[kmax, α] == A^2/2, 
   0 < kmax < Pi} /. {A -> 1, α -> 1} // FullSimplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Why was what I wrote not yielding the same answer?

Comment: The text indicates that `alpha = 1` but your code used `alpha = 0.7`; also you truncated the sum with `M = 5` rather than using `M = Infinity`.

Comment: I've tried plotting the kmax values for a range of alpha, but I see lots of these kind of messages: https://i.imgur.com/EZkm5cq.png Does that happen because finding the value kmax is difficult for Mathematica to do?